# How can I add alert button to the radio option if I have multiple select tags with same option?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Note: Multiple select tags were added using for loop in PHP.The problem I am facing is when I have multiple select tags with same options I could not know which select is calling selectfun()
`<?php`

```
       $dynamicTable= "";
       for ($x = 1; $x <= $a; $x++) {

        $dynamicTable .= "<tr><td>";
        $dynamicTable .= $x;
        $dynamicTable .= "</td><td><input type='text'></td>
      <td><input type='text'></td>
      <td>
        <select name='choose' class='choose' onclick='selectfun()'>
        <select name='choose' class='choose' onclick='selectfun()'>
         <option value='text'>VAR CHAR</option>
         <option value='number'>NUMBER</option>
         <option value='radio'>RADIO</option>
       </select>
      ?>
    }
    echo $dynamicTable;
<script>
function selectfun() {
  var selectBox = document.querySelectorAll(".choose")[?];
  var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
  if (selectedValue == 'radio') { 
    alert("Hi");
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting Multiple Radio Buttons With Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132373/selecting-multiple-radio-buttons-with-alert)

Comment: you can pass `index` as first parameter of `selectfun(index)` in PHP loop.

Comment: [Prime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14272274/prime) can you please be more specific? I mean I need code.

Comment: Will you post more code including php loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function selectfun(elem){
if(elem.value == 'radio'){
    alert(elem.value);
}
else{
    alert('it is not radio')
    }
}
```

```html
 <select name='choose' class='choose' onclick='selectfun(this)'>
 <option value='text'>VAR CHAR</option>
 <option value='number'>NUMBER</option>
 <option value='radio'>RADIO</option>
 </select>
  <select name='choose' class='choose' onclick='selectfun(this)'>
 <option value='text'>VAR CHAR</option>
 <option value='number'>NUMBER</option>
 <option value='radio'>RADIO</option>
 </select>
```

you can use pass `parameter` from the click event, [here](https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/javascript/how-to-pass-and-use-arguments-to-code-with-javascript/) you can read more about how to pass the parameter from the functions in JS.

Answer (score 1):

**Add an event value to the onchange event**
*(I assume you want the selected value not that the select has been clicked)*

```
<select id='select1' name='choose' class='choose' onchange=selectfun(event);>
    <option value='text'>VAR CHAR</option>
    <option value='number'>NUMBER</option>
    <option value='radio'>RADIO</option>
</select>

<select id='select2' name='choose' class='choose' onchange=selectfun(event);>
    <option value='text'>VAR CHAR</option>
    <option value='number'>NUMBER</option>
    <option value='radio'>RADIO</option>
</select>

<select id='select3' name='choose' class='choose' onchange=selectfun(event);>
    <option value='text'>VAR CHAR</option>
    <option value='number'>NUMBER</option>
    <option value='radio'>RADIO</option>
</select>
```

**Get selection info using the event**

```
function selectfun(event){
    alert(event.target.id + " Selected " +  event.target.value);
}
```

I added an ID to each select in this example so you can see from the output that it is the value from that specific select.

**Issue**
Only issue with this is if VAR CHAR is selected no change will occur so the function won't be fired.

**Solution**
I suggest adding an option that is an unset position that asked for a selection.

```
<select id='select1' name='choose' class='choose' onchange=selectfun(event);>
    <option value=''>SELECT VALUE</option>
    <option value='text'>VAR CHAR</option>
    <option value='number'>NUMBER</option>
    <option value='radio'>RADIO</option>
</select>
```